# Openerp pos pricelist value in receipt

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I'm using pricelist in Openerp POS. I like to show both public price and discounted pricelist price in pos receipt. But currently only the pricelist price alone is displayed in the receipt. Only pricelist price is getting displayed, But the actual price is not displayed in receipt. I want customer to know that there are getting the product for discounted price. Any suggestion for this?

Example:

Ice Cream (Public Price): 10$

Ice Cream (Price List Price): 9$ (I want to give 10% discount)

In the receipt, price is displayed as just 9$ instead of Actual Price 10$, Discounted Price 9$.

Answer (score 0):

This is for odoo-8.0 
You can change this on the receipt report (Settings > User

interface > Views ---> filter on report_receipt (Qweb view))

It's a POS, it's not a sales order, this is a different approach.

Comment: Yes but how to get the public price of the product in report_receipt? such that we can display public and pricelist price in receipt. Right now only pricelist price is availave in report_receipt.